# Errors accessing .NET class method overloads in IronPython

Tags: python, ironpython

I have a class I've written in C#. The class has two methods, the signatures being:

```
bool Navigate(string url)
bool Navigate(Uri url)
```

From what I gather, the IronPython runtime is supposed to try and select the best overload based on the passed-in argument. In my case, I'm passing in a string which I know to be non-null, yet I get the following exception:

> Multiple targets could match: Navigate(Uri), Navigate(str)

Seeing as my argument is blatantly a string, why does IronPython insist that multiple targets could match? System.String does not cast to System.Uri and as such the second method overload should not be a viable candidate for selection...

Comment: Interesting, not had this problem myself nor would I know how to advise though I'm afraid.

Comment: @Nathan, I couldn't reproduce the problem. I used your two signatures, and it worked as expected. I'm using IronPython 2.6 Final.

Comment: There's obviously some other kind of weirdness going on in the rest of my class then. I found a workaround in the meantime, but my class is a bit too tied to my framework to easily publish it here for testing.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like somehow IronPython is deciding that it can convert strings to `Uri`s. Perhaps this is a "feature", I don't know. You could do something like the following ([source](http://ironpython.net/documentation/dotnet/dotnet.html#method-overloads)):

```
navigate_string = myObj.Navigate.Overloads[type("")]
navigate_string("asdf")
```