# Multiple targets could match: int

Tags: c#, python-2.7, ironpython

I have extend IronPython with a function (no overloads, no generics, always returns string)

```
public string get_in_param(string key)
```

In my python script I have a call

```
step = int(myextension.get_in_param("step"))
```

There I - sometimes - get

> Multiple targets could match: int(type, IList[Byte]), int(type, object), int(type, Extensible[float])

I read [IronPython overload resolution on generic types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907886/ironpython-overload-resolution-on-generic-types) about possible overloads, but my function always returns string, and int() is built in. Also, something like

```
step = int.Overloads[str](myextension.get_in_param("step"))
```

is not working (runtime error that Overloads is invalid).

"step" always contains the string representation of an integer. I am using IronPython 2.7.4 embedded into an application.

Why the sporadic error, and how to fix it?

**Update:**

More details on get_in_param:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = ...

public string get_in_param(string key)
{
    string res = null;
    dict.TryGetValue(key);
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Would you like to show us the complete implementation of `get_in_param` and how you pass it to your ip context? How do you create `myextension`?

Comment: @BendEg Implementation of get_in_param is very straightforward, it gets a value from a Dictionary<string, string>. I will add code in original post. The rest of the IronPython integration is in external code of the application, I just have source access to a plugin I am writing, my code registers an interface and implementation to provide this functionality that is then provided to IronPython outside of my code.

Comment: Only for testing purpose, what does this do: `step = int(str(myextension.get_in_param("step")))`

Comment: I did not have output of the actual value I was using.. now sometimes on print, it is empty. So I guess the value sometimes comes in as null and there is a timing problem outside of the code with clearing/filling the dictionary. IronPython then has the problem with the string being null with above message.